# React - Page doesn't display when using the browser back button

Tags: reactjs, back, mern

I have looked through a lot of related topics and have so far been unable to resolve my problem with my MERN app.

**When I try to go to another website and use the browser back button, some pages doesn't show.**

**Instead, I can only see my json file / API response...**
**I need to refresh the page for it to be displayed correctly.**

If, for example, you are going to : https://www.website.org/royalty-free-music/cinematic/page-1, try to go to another website and click to the go back button in your browser, the page doesn't display...

**It only happend when you exit the website, go to another one and coming back with the go back button.... it doesn't happend when you stay on the website.**

---

There is no problem with the pages:

https://www.website.org/how-to-use-our-music 
or
https://www.website.org/license-agreement ...

It only happend for the pages like this :

`https://website.com/royalty-free-music/:category/page-:page`

For example:

https://www.website.org/royalty-free-music/all/page-1
or
https://www.website.org/royalty-free-music/corporate/page-2

---

I think it might be **related to the state** in `client/src/components/tracks/Tracks.js` but I don't know what to fix....

---

Thank you in advance for you help (:

Comment: Fun fact, there is no problem in Chrome when opening the dev tools with "Disable cache" checked in "Network" tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably comes from a browser cache problem. It's a single page app using React, so you need to always go through the front app `index.html`. For this you correctly serve `index.html` on a [wildcard route](https://github.com/Karaza/joystock/blob/master/server.js#L107) `/*` declared after your other routes, and you also use some middleware (history fallback). 
But as you declared the same route on the client **and** the server: `/royalty-free-music/all/page-1` the browser may look in the cache for the response and use the one provided by the server (JSON data) instead of the one corresponding to the front application.

You may solve this problem in two ways:

- obviously, change the server URL, or maybe prefix it with `api`. It would be semantically more correct (IMO) as server and front-end routes do not serve the same purpose (you are not dealing with server side rendering here)
- disable cache on the server route by using `res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private')` in your route.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!
At first, when I prefixed the route with `api`, the route didn't work anymore and I had to remove the history-fallback middleware for it to works correctly.
Didn't need to disable the cache after that.