# React return json instead html and css when I press button back on mouse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have web application (backend - node.js and frontend react) with two pages. The first page is menu and second page is orders. When I go from orders to menu and press on mouse button back, I get json from web page. Data are load correctly, but page not show html and only json. When I press back in browser, all is correct.
There is my code for Order.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MyNavbar from './MyNavbar';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Alert} from 'reactstrap';
import BuildOrder from './BuildOrder';

class Order extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        orders: [],
        visible: false,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getOrders();
    if (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.alertMessage) {
        this.handleUpdateStatus(this.props.location.state.alertColor, this.props.location.state.alertMessage);
    }
}

handleUpdateStatus(color, message) {
    this.setState({alertColor: color, alertMessage: message});
    this.onShowAlert();
}

getOrders() {
    const url = '/orders';
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.setState({orders: response.data})
    });
};

onShowAlert = () => {
    this.setState({visible: true}, () => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({visible: false},
                this.props.history.replace({...this.props.location.pathname, state: {}}))
        }, 5000)
    });
};

toggle() {
    this.setState({
        visible: !this.state.visible
    });
};

handleClickDelete = order => {
    axios.delete('/order', { data: { name: order.name, build: order.build } }).then((message) => {
          this.getOrders();
          this.handleUpdateStatus(message.data.type, message.data.content);
      }
    )
      .catch((err) => {
          this.getOrders();
          this.handleUpdateStatus('danger', err.message);
      });
};

handleClickUpdate(evt, data) {
    axios({
        method: 'put',
        url: '/orders',
        headers: {},
        data: data
    }).then(() => {
            this.handleUpdateStatus('success', 'Platba aktualizována');
        }
    ).catch((err) => {
        this.handleUpdateStatus('danger', err.message);
    });
}

handleClickOrder(evt, data) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/send/order',
        headers: {},
        data: data
    }).then((message) => {
          this.handleUpdateStatus(message.data.type, message.data.content);
      }
    ).catch((err) => {
        this.handleUpdateStatus('danger', err.message);
    });
}

getOnTop(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};

render() {
    const orders = this.state.orders;
    let ordersBuildA = [];
    let ordersBuildB = [];

    let handleClickDelete = this.handleClickDelete;
    let handleClickUpdate = this.handleClickUpdate.bind(this);
    let handleClickOrder = this.handleClickOrder.bind(this);
    let getOnTop = this.getOnTop;

    return (
        <div>
            {orders.filter(order => order.build === 'A').forEach(order => ordersBuildA.push(order))}
            {orders.filter(order => order.build === 'B').forEach(order => ordersBuildB.push(order))}
            <MyNavbar/>
            <Alert className="text-center" color={this.state.alertColor} isOpen={this.state.visible}
                   toggle={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
                {this.state.alertMessage}
            </Alert>
            <div className="container">
                <BuildOrder build="A" orders={ordersBuildA} handleClickDelete={handleClickDelete.bind(this)}
                            handleClickUpdate={handleClickUpdate.bind(this)} handleClickOrder={handleClickOrder.bind(this)} getOnTop={getOnTop.bind(this)}/>
                <BuildOrder build="B" orders={ordersBuildB} handleClickDelete={handleClickDelete.bind(this)}
                            handleClickUpdate={handleClickUpdate.bind(this)} handleClickOrder={handleClickOrder.bind(this)} getOnTop={getOnTop.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Order;
```

And index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import NotFound from './componets/NotFound';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Order from './componets/Order';

const RouterMapping = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={App}/>
            <Route path='/orders' exact component={Order}/>
            <Route exact component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <RouterMapping/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

module.hot.accept();
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

EDIT.
There is full project
https://bitbucket.org/mjedle/obedy_docker/src/master/

Comment: You have two of this kind of statements `{orders.filter(....).forEach(....)}`. `.forEach` doesn't return anything. What are you trying to do ?.

Comment: Any way you could provide an example with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) so we can see all the components working together?

Comment: @Titus it sould by filter all orders, which have build type A or B and insert into relevant array

Comment: Yes but you have those statements inside of the JSX code. If they don't return anything (don't add anything to the DOM) they should be outside, before the `return` statement.

Comment: @Titus, ok. But this statement return data. Functionality should be ok. I have problem, then on page is json and not html, when i press back button on mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that I call the same url for frontend and backend. When I added /api/orders to backend all is ok.
[React - Page doesn't display when using the browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008265/react-page-doesnt-display-when-using-the-browser-back-button)